# Split Bounty between two answers?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have recently put a bounty on a rechargeable battery question here:

[What can I use to power my Raspberry Pi Zero with rechargeable battery?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40181/what-can-i-use-to-power-my-raspberry-pi-zero-with-rechargeable-battery/40582#40582)

Many answers give viable batteries, but none of them give a way to connect them.

One answer gives a way to connect the batteries, but no battery. I feel the bounty should be split. Who should I give the bounty to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something we control.  The system is, thankfully, automated to a great extent and prevents me from finding too many ways to spend my time.  Bounties are pretty straight-forward and you've read the docs.

I.e., you have to make a decision. I would encourage you to accept [Tai's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40543/5538).  The reason I say that is there is a bigger picture here. I think you have probably read [ppumkin's concerns](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/697/5538), and please also read my answer there for some clarification about this.

That question would be helpful in the future for other people looking for miracle cures if we had an accepted answer that introduced a clear sense of realism.  I am not saying that to insult you, my snarkiness is for brevity.  It is your choice, but I would appreciate it if you could give all this some thought first.  I am also happy to chat with you in private about these issues if you would like to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that Tai's is the most well thought out and helpful so I gave it to him.